# How element selector is more specific than id selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

As I understand elements are least specific. (element vs id).
Please help me in understanding the specificity of selectors generally.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="firstDiv">FIRST Div inside CONTAINER</div>
    <div id="secondDiv">SECOND Div inside CONTAINER</div>
</div>
```

```css
body{
    width: 780px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#container > div:not(:last-of-type){
    margin-bottom: 0px; /*How its more specific than ID selector below? */
}
#container {
    border: 15px solid orange;
    padding: 10px;
}
#firstDiv{
    margin: 50px; /*This is not taking effect*/
    border: 5px solid blueviolet;
}
#secondDiv{
    border: 5px solid brown;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2RRq/

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To understand CSS specificity, read [The Specificity Wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html). There’s a handy reference sheet, too:

[image]

So, a selector like `#foo` would have `1,0,0` specificity, while an element selector like `p` would have `0,0,1` specificity. Out of these two, the ID selector would “win” as `100` is greater than `1`.

A more specific (heh) version which also includes pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes can be found here: http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/

[image]

Comment: How on earth have I *not* seen this?! This is brilliant.

Comment: Specificity doesn't count ">" for direct child in its formula?

Comment: @Shawn: Have a look at the last picture, where it says: *`*`,+,>,~: The universal selector has no value and combinators do not increase specificity.* Also I assume you have had a look at the specs by now and it is clearly defined how the specificity is computed, so no, it does not count.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for making me understand all this concept easily.

Comment: Nonetheless chrome just decided to ditch all these rules and make my previously specified parent div color show instead of the id color. Troubleshooting incoming..

Answer (score 2):

When applying rules, selector specificity is calculated by counting *all* simple selectors (linked by any combinators), and not just the key selector. That means you're not just comparing these two selectors:

```css
div
#firstDiv
```

But you're comparing these two selectors:

```css
#container > div:not(:last-of-type)
#firstDiv
```

Here, the first selector is more specific because it has:

- An ID selector, `#container`
- A type (element) selector, `div`; and
- A pseudo-class, which in this case is `:last-of-type`; the `:not()` pseudo-class itself doesn't count toward selector specificity

Whereas the second selector only consists of an ID. Note that combinators themselves like `>` in your first example don't count toward selector specificity.

There is an entire section in the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) covering how to calculate selector specificity.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor There is. [See my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9311237/96656)

Comment: @Shawn: Yes see the link in my comment. `#container > div:not(:last-of-type)` is `0-1-0-2` and `#firstDiv` is `0-1-0-0`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Child symbol doesn't count anywhere? ">"

Comment: Note that Selectors spec doesn’t mention how things like `style` attributes influence specificity.

Comment: @Mathias: Not in this spec, but in [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: @Mathias Bynens: Well, they don't. They influence the cascade.

Comment: @FelixKling Good catch! I still think it’s easier to think of selectors as fish and sharks.

Comment: @Mathias: I absolutely agree :)