# Why does an attribute selector have higher specificity than a class?

Tags: html, css

Why does the `input[type=number]` selector in the example below override the `.num` class selector?
Shouldn't both have a specificity of 1?

My expectation was that whichever was declared later would have overridden the former.

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}

input[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.num {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="num"> Why is the border not red (as requested by .num)?
```

Comment: Post your code example in your question, not jsFiddle

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: Use a specificity calculator like https://specificity.keegan.st/.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311237/15167500 - In a much older question on a similar topic, they are seeking the answer. Why does the type selector receive such a strong classification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Attribute selectors share the same level of specificity as CSS class selectors. In your example you have `input[type=number]` and `.num`.

- `input[type=number]` has a specificity of `0 0 1 1`, it has two selectors in it, an *element* `input` and *attribute* `[type=number]`.
- `.num`, has a specificity of `0 0 1 0` and only has one selector in it, a *class*.

Since `input[type=number]` has a higher specificity than `.num` it's style will always win out regardless of placement. If `input[type=number]` was changed to `[type=number]`, then placement would play a role as they'd both share a specificity of `0 0 1 0` and the latter would win out.

```css
input {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

/* Specificity - 0, 0, 1, 1 */
input[type="number"] {
  border-style: dotted;
}

/* Specificity - 0, 0, 1, 0 */
[type="number"] {
  border: 1px dashed indianred;
}

/* Specificity - 0, 0, 1, 0 */
.num {
  border-color: rebeccapurple;
}

/* Specificity - 0, 0, 1, 0 */
[type="number"] {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="num" name="number" value="0">
```

** Note: I only used the same CSS selector twice for demonstration purposes.* Notice which `border-style` wins out. Although there was an attempt to apply `dashed` and `solid` after `dotted`, neither was applied because of specificity. The cascade, which rule(s) came after another, is applied when specificity values are identical.

Comment: Switched this one to best answer because I think it would be more helpful to anyone else with the same question

Answer (score 2):

> Why does an attribute selector have higher specificity than a class?

They don't. Attribute and class selectors both have a specificity of 0,0,1,0.

> Why does the `input[type=number]` selector in the example below override the `.num` class selector? Shouldn't both have a specificity of 1?

A type selector (`input`) + an attribute selector (`[type=number]`) has a specificity of 0,0,1,1.

Comment: Thanks. `input[class=num]` then conveniently is better than just `.num` in this case because it has the same specificity as `input[type=number]`

Comment: You could also use `input.num`, which would be the same specificity as `input[class=num]`. You can use `[type=number]` if you want to set a base for all number inputs and then use `.num` as a special modifier to that base. In that instance just make sure `.num` comes after `[type=number]` so it wins out due both selectors having the same specificity value.

Comment: So does `input.num`

Answer (score 2):

To understand the specificity, let's first understand the [3 column specificity order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#how_is_specificity_calculated)

0. Inline styles (*which has more precedence over below three, but in general, it's not part of the 3 column specificity*)
1. ID selectors (*id ex. `#example`*)
2. Class selectors (*class, attributes & pseudo-classes. ex. `.myClass`, `[type="radio"]`, `:hover`*)
3. Type selectors (*elements & pseudo-elements. ex. `p`, `h1`, `::before`*)

> [`!important` exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception): If a style has `!important` flag, the important declaration applies no matter the specificity

In your example, the attribute selector `input[type='number']` has higher specificity than the class selector `.num`. Let's break down the specificity of each selector:

**Element with Attribute Selector** `input[type='number']`:

```
Specificity: 0, 1, 1 (one attribute selector, one element selector)
```

**Class Selector** `.num`:

```
Specificity: 0, 1, 0 (one class selector)
```

Although both selectors have a specificity of `1` in the second column (representing classes, attributes, or pseudo-classes), the attribute selector additionally has the Type selector specifity `1`, making its specificity higher. As a result, the styles defined by `input[type='number']` will take precedence over the styles defined by the class selector `.num`.

Here's a good article to understand specificity better: [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score -1):

In short, it's because your CSS is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#how_is_specificity_calculated) for *that type* of input.

A style for `input` or `.num` or `[type="input"]` would be using just one selector, but `input[type=number]` is a combination of *two* selectors.

*(Thanks @rozsazoltan.)*

Comment: "A style for input or .num or [type="input"] would be of equal weight by themselves" - **Are they all equal?** `input` - 0-0-1 is weaker than `.num` or `[type="input"]` - 0-1-0. Together, `input[type="input"]` is 0-1-1 - stronger than `.num` what alone just 0-1-0. **Try example in [playground](https://playcode.io/1718089).** The element selector always remains the weakest selector. See, it doesn't override the class or attribute selector.

Answer (score -1):

Type selectors (input, div, etc.) have a lower specificity than attribute selectors (**input[type=number]**).
Class selectors (**.num**) have a lower specificity than attribute selectors (**input[type=number]**).

In your case:
The **input[type=number]** selector has higher specificity than the **.num** class selector because an attribute selector (**[type=number]**) carries more weight than a class selector.
Although both selectors have a specificity of 1 in terms of the number of selectors, the type attribute selector (**input[type=number]**) takes precedence over the class selector (**.num**) because attribute selectors have higher specificity than class selectors.
Therefore, even if the .num class selector is declared later in the CSS, the **input[type=number]** selector will take precedence due to its higher specificity based on attribute selection.

If you want the **.num** class selector to override the **input[type=number]** styles, you would need to increase its specificity, either by adding more class selectors or using a more specific selector targeting the input elements with the .num class:

```
input {
  width: 100px;
}

input[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid #c0ffee;
}

/* Increase specificity for .num to override input[type=number] */
input.num {
  border: 2px solid #c55;
}
```

By combining the input and .num class selectors, you increase the specificity of the rule, allowing it to override the **input[type=number]** selector.

Answer (score -1):

#### Default cases

In the "CSS Specificity with Plankton, fish and sharks" example, the number-number-number-number-number classification represents specificity values, indicating the strength of CSS selectors. These numbers are interpreted as follows:

**- Third number (digits): Plankton level - 0-0-1** (Minimal impact)

- The number of type selectors and pseudo-elements.
- The Plankton level is the lowest. Selectors at this level are the weakest and can be easily overridden by fish and shark levels.
  In the example, there is no specific selector provided, so the numbers only indicate the different levels. In reality, selectors would be part of this classification. Specificity values help CSS engines determine which style rule applies to a particular element when an element matches multiple rules. The higher the specificity value, the higher the priority of the style.

**- Second number (tens): Fish level - 0-1-0** (Stronger than the previous)

- The number of class selectors, attributs selectors, and pseudo-classes.
- The Fish level is the second-highest. Selectors at this level are stronger than plankton but weaker than sharks.

**- First number (hundreds): Shark level - 1-0-0** (Stronger than the previous)

- The number of ID selectors.
- The Shark level is the absolute strongest. To override them, at least an equal number of sharks or one of the special cases is required.

#### Special cases

In the next example, inline `style` and `!important` are two special cases, illustrated with the metaphors of "ship" and "atomic bomb":

**- Ship (thousands): 1-0-0-0** (Stronger than the previous)

- This specificity level is represented by the metaphor of a "ship". It refers to the specificity gained by directly styling an element using the style attribute. It is uniquely strong, surpassing all other forms of specificity.

**- Atomic Bomb (tens of thousands): 1-0-0-0-0** (Stronger than the previous)

- The specificity level of `!important` is depicted with the metaphor of an "atomic bomb". It is a special flag added to a style rule after the properties. This flag means that this rule overrides everything, bypassing the usual specificity rules. `!important` is the highest specificity flag, overriding all other styles, including styles applied directly to the element. Therefore, the "atomic bomb" is the most powerful tool for manipulating specificity values.
- Despite its strength, it is not recommended to use it as it complicates the transparency of CSS. If we want to override something, let's do it with the appropriate and nuanced use of default cases.

[image: CSS Specificity]

As shown in the diagram, if we concatenate these, we need to sum up the points for each level. If an element is styled in multiple ways, the styling with the highest level will take precedence.

#### In summary

In the specific example of the question, `input[type=number]` proves stronger than `.num` because it denotes two levels of identification: `input` and `[type=number]`. These are valid selectors individually, but together, they have higher specificity.

If we bring up a simpler example between `[type=number]` and `.num`, it will be understandable that due to their equal specificity, the last declaration will prevail.

```css
/* 0-1-0                 (searchable on the diagram: 2nd row, 3rd cell) */
[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

/* 0-1-0                 (searchable on the diagram: 2nd row, 2nd cell) */
.num {
  border: 2px solid red; /* WIN (last highest level: 0-1-0) */
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="num">
```

If both were applied to an input again, they would have equal strength, so once again, the last one would take effect.

```css
/* input:         0-0-1  (1rd row, 2nd cell) */
/* [type=number]: 0-1-0  (2nd row, 3rd cell) */
/* Summary:       0-1-1  (searchable on the diagram: 3rd row, 2nd cell) */
input[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

/* input:         0-0-1  (1rd row, 2nd cell) */
/* .num:          0-1-0  (2nd row, 2nd cell) */
/* Summary:       0-1-1  (searchable on the diagram: 3rd row, 1st cell) */
input.num {
  border: 2px solid red; /* WIN (last highest level: 0-1-1) */
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="num">
```

But in the question, only `[type=number]` received a stronger definition, so `.num` alone may not be sufficient for overriding.

```css
/* input:         0-0-1  (1rd row, 2nd cell) */
/* [type=number]: 0-1-0  (2nd row, 3rd cell) */
/* Summary:       0-1-1  (searchable on the diagram: 3rd row, 2nd cell) */
input[type=number] {
  border: 2px solid green; /* WIN (0-1-1 > 0-1-0) */
}

/* 0-1-0                 (searchable on the diagram: 2nd row, 2nd cell) */
.num {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="num">
```

Answer (score -2):

> Attribute selectors share the same level of specificity as CSS class selectors

It depends if the Attribute Selector & the Class Selector are qualified with an Element Selector or not.

Consider

Attribute Selector `[data-foo="underline"]`
Specificity: [0, 1, 0]

Class Selector `.underline`
Specificity: [0, 1, 0]

Attribute Selector (Qualified with an Element Selector) `u[data-foo="underline"]`
Specificity: [0, 2, 0]

Class Selector (Qualified with an Element Selector) `u.underline`
Specificity: [0, 2, 0]

So basically the Attribute Selector (not qualified with a element selector) will have the same specificity as the Class Selector (not qualified with a element selector)

The Attribute Selector (qualified with a element selector) will have the same specificity as the Class Selector (qualified with a element selector)

However if the Attribute Selector or the Class Selector are qualified with an Element Selector than they will not have the same specificity