# Bootstrap 5: make input file the same height of other fields

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using this simple template to show a registration form with file attachment field:

```css
/* the problem is here when I try to modify the height for myself */
.mycustom {
  line-height: 2.75;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap@5.3.2 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- code -->
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <main>
      <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
          <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <input type="file" class="form-control mycustom" id="formFiles" name="files" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload" required>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>            
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <small class="text-muted">By clicking Sign up, you agree to the terms of use.</small>
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

I add this piece of CSS to have the same height in input file but I would like to know if exists a responsive way to specify height:

```css
.mycustom{
  line-height: 2.75;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

**EDIT:** I wish to specify the same height for `file input` field preserving template responsiveness, not how to specify a css.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap framework was developed with strict and powerful CSS class references to define styles. You can learn more about their strength and better understanding in another question: [Why does an attribute selector have higher specificity than a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781671/15167500).

[image: problem]

The linked answer reveals that there are three options to override the original style.

#### Problem with equally strong references

If you want to override a reference with equal strength, you generally need to append it later in the respective file. However, in this case, we are dealing with two different files. The first one is the initially loaded `bootstrap.min.css`, and the other is your own `style.css` code. Since they are not in the same file, you can only override the settings of the first file with stronger references.

#### Solution # 1 - `!important`

It is not recommended to use this if you want to write clear and understandable code. However, it is a straightforward choice if you need quick results.

```css
.mycustom {
  line-height: 200px !important; /* here */
}
```

```css
.mycustom {
  line-height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap@5.3.2 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- code -->
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <main>
      <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
          <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <input type="file" class="form-control mycustom" id="formFiles" name="files" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload" required>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>            
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <small class="text-muted">By clicking Sign up, you agree to the terms of use.</small>
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution # 2 - `inline <div style="...">`

Not reusable. I believe that in most cases, reusability is an important consideration over inline styles.

```html
<input
  type="file"
  class="form-control"
  style="line-height: 200px;"
  id="formFiles"
  name="files"
  aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04"
  aria-label="Upload"
  required
>
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap@5.3.2 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- code -->
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <main>
      <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
          <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <!-- here style="..." -->
          <input type="file" class="form-control" style="line-height: 200px;" id="formFiles" name="files" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload" required>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>            
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <small class="text-muted">By clicking Sign up, you agree to the terms of use.</small>
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution # 3 - stronger rule as the original (Recommended)

If you prefer to avoid using !important and favor reusable CSS classes over inline styles, as recommended in most cases, then you just need to create as strong an override as the original formatting.

```css
/* Original - Strong: 0-1-0 */
.form-control {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* Your attempt - Strong: 0-1-0 */
/* 
   equally strong... theoretically it would work,
   but in practice it doesn't because it's not defined
   in the original file...
   therefore, the .form-control defined in the original
   bootstrap.min.css file, which is loaded earlier,
   becomes the benchmark --> it can only be overridden
   with a stronger rule
*/
.mycustom {
  line-height: 200px !important; /* here */
}

/*How to write a stronger rule? There are various options available to us.*/

/* Defining a stronger rule - Strong: 0-2-0 */
.form-control.mycustom {
  line-height: 200px !important; /* working - overrides the original */
}

/* OR... */

/* Defining a stronger rule - Strong: 0-1-1 */
input.form-control {
  line-height: 200px !important; /* working - overrides the original */
}

/* and many more almost infinite combinations are possible, depending on when you want to apply the override */
```

```css
.form-control.mycustom {
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap@5.3.2 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- code -->
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <main>
      <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
          <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <input type="file" class="mycustom form-control" id="formFiles" name="files" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload" required>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>            
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <small class="text-muted">By clicking Sign up, you agree to the terms of use.</small>
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### More information

- [How to work CSS Specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781671/15167500) - StackOverflow Answer
- [How is specificity calculated?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) - MDN Docs