# Bootstrap style import has a problem in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm making a blog website using React.js and for its navbar I'm using Bootstrap. The problem is that when I import the Bootstrap styles, it'll change the whole website style such as fonts, flexbox, and grid.

I import this line: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

And from this:

[image: Before design]

Coverts to this:

[image: After design]

I want it to just be applied on my navbar, not other places.
I would appreciate the assistant people...

Comment: Now, Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 5? Since both are marked, it's hard to decide which one to use.

Comment: Hi, Bootstrap 5

Comment: Can you share the source code (an example that can reproduce the content shown in the picture)? It's difficult to debug from an image. Bootstrap implements its styles with strong specificity, making their overrides possible only with stronger references. It may happen that similar class names or elements are used by Bootstrap, and during Bootstrap implementation, your style references may not be strong enough for enforcement. I have elaborated on this further in a earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77811139/15167500

Comment: Understanding [CSS Specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501036/why-does-an-attribute-selector-have-higher-specificity-than-a-class/77781671#77781671) will help you determine if your rule is strong enough for enforcement.