# Using input[type='checkbox']:checked selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to display or hide a paragraph in a html page. The html code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show"> Show/Hide
<p id="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Then I use CSS3 to hide/show the paragraph:

```
 #toggle {
 display:none;
 }

#show:checked ~ p {
    display: block;
}
```

This does work. But if I try:

```
#toggle {
  display:none;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ p {
   display: block;
   }
```

this doesn't work anymore. I can't understand why. Is there any error in this selector?

```
  input[type='checkbox']:checked
```

Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: specificity issue ... use this instead `#show:checked ~ p#toggle` .. ID selector is more specific so the checked style never apply

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How element selector is more specific than id selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311165/how-element-selector-is-more-specific-than-id-selector)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637343/what-are-the-priorities-among-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the CSS specificity.
When looking at the [specificity hierarchy](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/#specificity-hierarchy) , you'll see that **id** will go above the **element**.

That means that
`#toggle` is more specific then:
`input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ p`
and therefor will the id overrule the element selector.

So, use:

```css
#toggle {
  display: none;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ p#toggle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show"> Show/Hide
  <p id="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Or:

```css
input[type='checkbox'] ~ p{
  display: none;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show"> Show/Hide
  <p id="toggle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `you'll see that id will go above (pseudo)classes.` ? it's about ID and element selector, pseudo class and classes has nothing to do here.