# div p { margin-bottom: 10px;} not working

Tags: html, css

`div p { margin-bottom: 10px;}` is not working. Not sure what is wrong here.

```
.p1, .p2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    }
```

is works fine, but `div p {...}` is not working.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: Royalblue; /*#f0f0f0;*/
  margin: 0px;
}

.div {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.p1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.p2 {
    margin: 0;
}

div p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>  
        
        <div class="div">
      
            <p class="p1">Welcome to Homepage</p>
            <p class="p2">Lorem Ipsum</p>
            
        </div>
   
</body>
```

Comment: Because the *class* `.p1` has higher specificity than the combined elements `div p` so that rule takes precedence. The search terms you want are "css specificity"; there are discrete rules which assign "weights" to different selectors to help the browser determine precedence when cascading styles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311165/how-element-selector-is-more-specific-than-id-selector

Answer (score 2):

Because of Specificity, the class `.p1` rule is overriding the `div p` rule. If you delete the `margin: 0` from the class rule, it should work, as there will be no competition between rules and the 10px can apply.

Some reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: deleting the margin would change his margin he set for the class though.

Comment: He never stated that he needed that rule, so I’ll just assume he’s a smart guy and that he will continue reading/learning and figure out a way to make it work if that’s what he actually needs.

Comment: Why does he have it there is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should not work according `css selector precedence` rules. According `css selector precedence` rules `class` selector value is 10 and for `tag` selector value is 1. So from your code we can calculate easily:

`.p1` or `.p2` precedence value = 10

`div p` precedence value is 1 + 1 = 2

That's why it is  `div p {...}` selector not working.

You can learn more from here about CSS precedence rules: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score -1):

You have to put either `.p1` or `.p2`. Style the css for each of them separately

```
.p1 { margin-bottom: 10px;}

.p2 { margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should try this it help full it's here class inside another class.

Code:

```
    .div .p1 { margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

Here (.) is the class identifier.

Comment: give me reason of down voters it's working for me so i can help to solve problem.